# MAGENTO - Add data to custom module

Tags: database, magento, module, insert, magento-1.7

i am new in magento, i am developing a custom module to save some information for every logged client, but my problem is: i cant add data to my table, so this is what i already did:

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Desing_ControlApp>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Desing_ControlApp>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <Desing_ControlApp>
            <class>Desing_ControlApp_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Desing_ControlApp_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </Desing_ControlApp>
        <Desing_ControlApp_mysql4>
            <class>Desing_ControlApp_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <Desing_ControlApp>
                    <table>Desing_ControlApp</table>
                </Desing_ControlApp>
            </entities>
        </Desing_ControlApp_mysql4>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <controlapp>
        <class>Desing_ControlApp_Helper</class>
      </controlapp>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <controlapp>
        <class>Desing_ControlApp_Block</class>
      </controlapp>
    </blocks>
    <resources>
      <controlapp_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Desing_ControlApp</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </controlapp_setup>
      <controlapp_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </controlapp_write>
      <controlapp_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </controlapp_read>
    </resources>
    <events> 
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <Desing_ControlApp>
                        <class>Desing_ControlApp/Observer</class>
                        <method>verificarApp</method>
                    </Desing_ControlApp>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>       
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <controlapp>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Desing_ControlApp</module>
          <frontName>admin_controlapp</frontName>
        </args>
      </controlapp>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <controlapp module="controlapp">
        <title>ControlApp</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <controlappbackend module="controlapp">
            <title>GENERAL CODE</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_controlapp/adminhtml_controlappbackend</action>
          </controlappbackend>
        </children>
      </controlapp>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <controlapp translate="title" module="controlapp">
              <title>ControlApp</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <controlappbackend translate="title">
            <title>GENERAL CODE</title>
          </controlappbackend>
              </children>
            </controlapp>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <controlapp>
          <file>controlapp.xml</file>
        </controlapp>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

i add the table here in mysql4_install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup(); 
    $sql=<<<SQLTEXT
        create table desinglog(
        log_id int not null auto_increment, 
        cliente_id smallint(8) unsigned  default '0', 
        token varchar(255) default'0',
        user varchar(255) default'0',
        primary key(log_id));
        SQLTEXT;
$installer->run($sql);
//demo 
//Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setId(null);
//demo 
$installer->endSetup();
```

so i have an observer and i want to insert data from there, i fonud a snipet to do it whith

```
$model = Mage::getModel('Desing_ControlApp/Desing_ControlApp')->....
```

but i cant access, every time the page show me "page is not working", so what i have to use instead Desing_ControlApp/Desing_ControlApp or i miss to write something? i cant found a good tutorial about these to. i found something here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9863/magento-connect-to-database-from-a-module but no results.

Answer (score 1):

> "*i cant add data to my table*" - the problem was table name is mismatching, you didn't call correct table name in config.

in Config `<table>Desing_ControlApp</table>`

```
<entities>
  <Desing_ControlApp>
     <table>Desing_ControlApp</table><!-- table name mismatch-->
  </Desing_ControlApp>
</entities>
```

but in setup file `mysql4_install-0.1.0.php` `create table desinglog(`

now change the config to call correct table then clear cache

Comment: hi, i have try <table>desinglog</table> and <table>Desing_ControlApp_desinglog</table>. My table name is desinglog, so question is, the table name has to be equal to the module name (Desing_ControlApp) or i am missing something more? thank you for the answer.

Comment: *the table name has to be equal to the module name?* no. *i am missing something more?* yes, you missed something.